# Apply css if element exists using CSS selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have header in such a way that I would like to hide my image and span's in my pheader div if "banner" exists. Is there a quick way to do this using CSS selectors? Below is the HTML code.

```html
<header>
  <div id="banner">
    <!-- main content -->
  </div>
  <div class="pheader">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <div id="hey-user" class="d2c-user-panel">
        <img src="../images/defaultHeadshot_lg.png" class="userimg">
        <!-- Hide This -->
        <span class="caret" id="down-arrow"></span>
        <span class="hey-user d2c-header-username"><b>Hello</span>
      </div>
</header>
```

Comment: check here http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/adjacent-sibling-selector-css-selector/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
#banner + .pheader img,
#banner + .pheader span {
display:none;
}
```

This selector only applies if `.pheader` is directly after `#banner`.

You might find this Tutsplus article useful:

[**The 30 CSS Selectors You Must Memorize**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

```css
.pheader {
  padding: 1em;
  background: lightblue;
}
#banner + .pheader img,
#banner + .pheader span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="banner">
    <!-- main content -->
  </div>
  <div class="pheader">
    <div class="user-panel">
      <div id="hey-user" class="d2c-user-panel">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-100-100-3.jpg" class="userimg" />
        <span class="caret" id="down-arrow">Arrow</span>
        <span class="hey-user d2c-header-username"><b>Hello</b></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

*It's probably worth noting that I've had to close a few divs in your original HTML structure which were missing from your code.*

Comment: Never knew about the `+` for logic in there, nice!

Comment: I have been trying this but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Ok let me check. I'll get back to this post.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I think I got the answer and its working now. Cheers. Don't need to create another question just for this as you've answered it already. Thanks again.

Comment: OK...you might want to delete the comments that are no obselete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Link https://jsfiddle.net/7bv53xqd/

```
#banner + .pheader img {
  display: none;
}

#banner + .pheader span {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: It does work in the jsfiddle but doesn't work for me. Let me investigate.